# I am not add stylesheet in the gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

My created block does not show...

```
const { __ } = wp.i18n;

const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { RichText } = wp.editor;

registerBlockType( 'block-examples/block-example-03-editable-block', {
  title:  __('MonnyEditabale Block'),
  icon: 'star-filled',
  category: 'layout',
  attributes: {
    label: {
      type: 'string',
      source: 'html',
      selector: '.label'
    },
    title: {
      type: 'string',
      source: 'html',
      selector: '.title'
    }
  },

  edit: ( props ) => {
    const { attributes: { content }, setAttributes, className } = props;
    const onChangeContent = ( newContent ) => {
        setAttributes( { content: newContent } );
    };
    return (
        <RichText
            tagName="p"
            className={ className }
            onChange={ onChangeContent }
            value={ content }
        />
    );
  },
   save: function(props) {
    const { label, title } = props.attributes

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="label">
          <RichText.Content
            value={ label }
          />
        </div>
        <div className="title">
          <RichText.Content
            value={ title }
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
} );
```

Comment: plz ans my question...

Answer (score 0):

You need to enqueue the block scripts at the correct place in php too. Read the very good block editor handbook on howto [create your first block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/).